# Django-Tastypie: Authentication&Authorization

Tags: django, authorization, tastypie, django-authentication

I have a quick question. For my API.py file I have the following code:

```
class MyAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):
def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':     
        return True
    else:
        #group_name = request.body('group')
        #if Group.objects.filter(name = group_name):
        #   return super(MyAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)
        return super(MyAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs) 

class MyAuthorization(DjangoAuthorization): #checks permissions
def is_authorized(self, request, object=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return True
    return super(MyAuthorization, self).is_authorized(request, object)

class Sys_teamResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = Sys_team.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'sys_team'
    filtering = { 'sys_team' : ALL }
    authentication = MyAuthentication()
    authorization = MyAuthorization()
    validation = FormValidation(form_class=Sys_team_Form)
    allowed_methods = ['get','post','put']
```

This code works fine but I was curious what would happenwhen I replaced `return super(MyAuthorization, self).is_authorized(request, object)` with `return False`. Conceptually, this should deny all permissions of the authenticated user and deny them from POSTING to the database. However, the user is still able to. I was wondering why that was? Also, regarding the commented out code above, I'm trying to authenticate the user only if he belongs to a certain group. However, when I try `request.body('group')`, I get the error str object is not callable. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for commented code and str object is not callable:**

request.data contains the incoming post data in string normally in json. As request.data is string doing following complains about **str object is not callable**.

```
group_name = request.body('group')
```

So you can use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) convert incoming json to python dictionary and you can access incoming data. So you can have something as follows:

```
class MyAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'GET':     
        return True
    else:
        import json

        group_name = json.loads(request.body)['group']

        if Group.objects.filter(name = group_name):
            return super(MyAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)

        return super(MyAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)
```